# error when selecting multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

```
SELECT pc_info_tbl.`serial_id` "Serial Number",
       pc_info_tbl.`replacement_warranty_date` "Replacement Warranty",
       pc_info_tbl.`service_warranty_date` "Service Warranty",
       personel_tbl.`fname` "First Name",
       personel_tbl.`mname` "Middle Name",
       personel_tbl.`lname` "Last Name",
       repair_records_tbl.`repair_date` "Repair Date",
       repair_records_tbl.`service_slip_no` "Service Slip Number",
       repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` "ITMD Personnel",
       repair_records_tbl.`notes` "Notes"
  FROM repair_records_tbl,
       itmd_personel_tbl,
       pc_info_tbl,
       personel_tbl
 WHERE repair_records_tbl.`personel_id` = personel_tbl.`personel_id`,
       repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`,
       repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` = itmd_personel_tbl.`itmd_personel_id`;
```

I want to select multiple tables, but I get error some where on `` repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`, repair_records_tbl.`i ``

Error Code: 1064
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`, repair_records_tbl.`i' at line 5

anyone can teach me the right syntax?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do an unconditional join across all these tables?

Comment: I'm really sorry guys, I completely forgot about the "AND/OR" condition. Stupid me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You separate column names while doing the select by comma but use AND/OR between the two where [clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and not separate them by comma:

```
SELECT pc_info_tbl.`serial_id` "Serial Number", pc_info_tbl.`replacement_warranty_date` "Replacement Warranty", pc_info_tbl.`service_warranty_date` "Service Warranty", personel_tbl.`fname` "First Name", personel_tbl.`mname` "Middle Name", personel_tbl.`lname` "Last Name", repair_records_tbl.`repair_date` "Repair Date", repair_records_tbl.`service_slip_no` "Service Slip Number", repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` "ITMD Personnel", repair_records_tbl.`notes` "Notes" 
FROM repair_records_tbl, itmd_personel_tbl, pc_info_tbl, personel_tbl 
WHERE repair_records_tbl.`personel_id` = personel_tbl.`personel_id`
AND repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`
AND repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` = itmd_personel_tbl.`itmd_personel_id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause  has a syntax error. May be you want to use `AND`

**Change**:

```
WHERE repair_records_tbl.`personel_id` = personel_tbl.`personel_id`, 
      repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`, 
      repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` = itmd_personel_tbl.`itmd_personel_id`;
```

**to**:

```
WHERE 
      repair_records_tbl.`personel_id` = personel_tbl.`personel_id`
  and repair_records_tbl.`serial_id` = pc_info_tbl.`serial_id`
  and repair_records_tbl.`itmd_personel_id` = itmd_personel_tbl.`itmd_personel_id`;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't realize I didn't put any condition in my query, I completely forgot about it.